# Linux process virtual address space's address range

Tags: c, linux

I'm on 32bit machine. From what I understand, User space's address ranges from `0x00000000` to `0xbfffffff`, and kernel's ranges from `0xc0000000` to `0xffffffff`.

But when I used pmap to see a process's memory allocation, I see that the library are loaded in around `0xf7777777`. Please see the attached screenshot. Does it mean those libraries are loaded in kernel space? And when I used `mmap()`, I got the address from `0xe0000000`. So, `mmap()` got memory from kernel space?

[image]

Comment: How much physical RAM do you have installed?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix What does that have to do with it? This is about virtual memory, not physical.

Comment: See http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/

Comment: @Barmar: it may have to do: for 32-bit systems the kernel maps the first 896MB of RAM to virtual addresses 0xC0000000 and up. If the computer has less than 896MB, not all the virtual space will be covered up and holes in the memory map show up, allowing the kernel to use them to reuse them to map user code or data

Comment: @Barmar: no, it's not. User has 3GB of virtual address. Kernel has 1GB.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix But `pmap` shows virtual address assignments. How that gets mapped to physical RAM is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm on 32bit machine. From what I understand, User space's address
>   ranges from 0x00000000 to 0xbfffffff, and kernel's ranges from
>   0xc0000000 to 0xffffffff.

Not exactly. Kernel memory space starts at `0xC0000000`, but it doesn't have to fill the entire GB. In fact, it fills up to virtual address `0xF7FFFFFF`. This covers `896MB` of physical memory. Virtual addresses `0xF8000000` and up are used as a `128MB` window for the kernel to map any region of physical memory beyond the `896MB` limit.

All user processes share the same memory map for virtual addresses `0xC0000000` and beyond, so if the kernel does not use its entire GB of virtual space, it may reuse part of it to map commonly used shared libraries, so every process can see them.

Comment: Some relevant kernel source: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h?v=3.19#L839 http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/Kconfig?v=3.19#L1238