# Entry Point of elf executable header

Tags: linux, memory-mapping, virtual-address-space

why is the entry point of elf is `0x8048320.` From [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488010/why-the-entry-point-address-in-my-executable-is-0x8048330-0x330-being-offset-of) question, its the virual address used by the operating system kernel to map the process. But [From This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426476/linux-process-virtual-address-spaces-address-range), the virual address where a process is mapped (in x86 processors) is `0xc0000000` (lower 3GB for user space and upper 1GB for kernel space). Now whats the theory behind this 0x8048320 starting point address. shouldn't it suppose to be `0c0000000h`??

Regards,

Comment: Entry Point from elf header:  `readelf -h a.out`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why the Entry point address in my executable is 0x8048330 (0x330 being offset of .text section)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488010/why-the-entry-point-address-in-my-executable-is-0x8048330-0x330-being-offset-of)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *entry point* is not the beginning of the mapping of the executable. It is the address of the first instruction that will be run when the program is started. As such, it is usually in the middle of the `.text` section.

If you use GCC or a compatible compiler, it will be the address of a function `_start` in `libc`. That is the function that will eventually call your `main()`.

From your example, `0x8048320` the *base address* will probably be `0x8000000` and the offset of `_start` will be `0x48320`.

In my machine, however:

```
$ readelf -h /usr/bin/ls | grep Entry
Entry point address:               0x404030
```

All these virtual addresses are usually up to the compiler and/or linker.